# Different UserControl inside a WPF ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I'm trying to show different UserControl inside a WPF ListBox with trigger.

I've try this approach, but with no luck.

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="FileManager.View.BackgroundOperationDialog.BackgroundOperationDialog"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FileManager.View.BackgroundOperationDialog"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    d:DesignHeight="450"
    d:DesignWidth="800"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="CopyMoveView">
            <local:MoveCopyDialog OperationDetails="{Binding}" ShowAllDetails="False" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ReductionTask">
            <local:ReductionTask />
        </DataTemplate>

        <Style x:Key="BgTasksContentStyle" TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RowData.Row.BackgroundTaskType}" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ReductionTask}" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RowData.Row.BackgroundTaskType}" Value="2">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource CopyMoveView}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding BackgroundOperations}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" Style="{StaticResource BgTasksContentStyle}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

In the listbox I can see the full namespace of the model FileManager.ViewModel.BackgroundOperationsModel.MoveCopyDialogModel but the component is not rendered.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It's an ObservableCollection

Comment: Can you post more of your class model that's in `BackgroundOperations` (which I'm guessing is `MoveCopyDialogModel`)? It's hard to say what's going wrong because your code works fine for me when I simplify the classes a bit for example purposes.

Comment: You must ensure that the values are either `1` or `2`. Otherwise there does not exist a default template to select in case the conditions fail and WPF will show the ToString() result (which is the fully qualified type name by default) of the actual data type.. If the values can be other than `1` and `2` you must assign a default template.

Comment: You should consider to extend DataTemplateSelector instead of implementing those triggers.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `DataTemplate` : 'CopyMoveView' as the `ControlTemplate` of `ContentPresenter` in `BgTasksContentStyle`. Consider using a `UIElement` as `DataTemplate` is not. See example here: [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.controltemplate?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)

Also why are you using `ContentPresenter` I'd advice you use `ContentControl`

Answer (score 0):

The solution proposed by BionicCode was illuminating.
After some attempts, I found that was missing a converter between `BackgroundTaskType` and the value used as trigger.

The following lines of code solve the problem.

```xml
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RowData.Row.BackgroundTaskType, Converter={StaticResource bgTaskConverter}}" Value="1">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ReductionTask}" />
</DataTrigger>
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RowData.Row.BackgroundTaskType, Converter={StaticResource bgTaskConverter}}" Value="2">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource CopyMoveView}" />
</DataTrigger>
```

Thanks for your support!